# Need recommendations for how to approach fireplace marble floor slab replacement

Tags: wood, floor, fireplace, trim, marble

I have a green marble slab in the floor in front of my fireplace (appx. 60"x24") that I've hated since I moved into my condo. It's really the color - I dislike the green, and wish this were a simpler white or black marble piece. I tried to upload images here for reference: https://imgur.com/a/usfza4Q

I asked the contractor who handled some of my condo renovations for a quote to replace it, and he quoted me $2,200 for labor and materials - primarily due to needing to remove the molding around my fireplace in order to replace it (since the slab sort of goes under the wall, it isn't just a flat rectangle). Note that I did request my contractor use a "remnant slab" for the quote he gave me, rather than any sort of custom-cut new slab, but he didn't itemize this out for me, so I'm not sure how much of this is labor vs. materials.

This is more than I would like to spend on a project like this, so I was hoping the community might have some budget-friendly suggestions for the best way to get this updated. **For those of you with more experience, how would you approach this project if it were yours?**

Some specific questions I had:

- **Would painting it be a viable solution?** I have no experience with painting marble (and am not very handy!), but I've seen some DIY
  videos for countertop painting kits from Home Depot. Curious if
  anyone has had good or bad experiences with trying to do this, any
  watch-outs, etc. I would also consider hiring someone to do this for
  me if this would be trickier than I'm expecting and beyond my (very
  low) DIY capabilities, but still cheaper than getting it replaced
  altogether.

  If I do actually want to get the marble replaced, **do you think the
  quote is fair for the job**, or is there a particular kind of
  tradesman I could hire to do this for cheaper? I don't really know
  what "type" of person to ask...this kind of project seems beyond a
  standard "handyman" I've used for mounting and patching things. How
  do you go about finding tradesman who specializes in working with
  floor tile/walls/molding/etc.?

  **Are there any other approaches, tactics or tips I should be considering?** I am pretty clueless when it comes to this stuff, so
  very much appreciate any guidance!

Thank you so much for any thoughts and suggestions!

Comment: That green "marble" is actually serpentine, and the white or gray "marbling" is the mineral chrysotile, aka asbestos ore. It's intact so it's not contaminating anything, but it's best not to abrade it for painting or to grind or pulverize it if you want to  remove it. Take it out in a single piece if feasible. Don't panic, I used to live near a serpentine quarry and I'm not dead yet.

Comment: I think the price is fair. The only other option is to tile over it, if you dont mind tripping.

Comment: Personally, I would think this simple to remove and replace—it could be broken up in place and removed in pieces.  A new piece could be fabricated and inserted without needing to remove the fireplace trim, IMO.  Just slide it under and let it fall into place (proper adhesive below, of course).